# Adding more parameters in angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

**EDIT: `angular.extend` and `Object.assign` both are just working fine which one should I use**

I am trying to add more values to angularjs service variable, but it overwrites the previous value. Here is an example code

```
var testModule = angular.module('testmodule', [])

  .controller('abc', function ($scope, mser) 
 {
  mser.aa = {a:5, b:2};
  mser.aa = {c:5, d:2};
  $scope.inps = mser.aa.a
 })

 .service('mser', function() {
  var aa = {}
  return aa
  });
```

Now as you know after `mser.aa = {c:5, d:2};` I will get `mser.aa.a` as `undefined` .
How can I avoid that and insert all values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the value of "mser.aa" with {c:5, d:2}. If you want to extend that object :

```
mser.aa = Object.assign(mser.aa, {c:5, d:2});
```

If you want to take advantage of `angular` methods instead of pure javascript `Object` methods, You can do it like this too:

```
angular.extend(mser.aa, {c:6, d:7});
```

Comment: should I use angular.extend or Object.assign ? I am developing an ionic application

Comment: Both does the same i.e copy own enumerable properties from the src object(s) to destination. You can use any one, But if you have nested objects in the src object and want to deep copy , use `angular.merge`. `assign` copies only the top level key references and not deep copy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use angulr.extend as follows:

```
mser.aa = {a:5, b:2};
angular.extend(mser.aa, {c:6, d:7});
```

This will extend the current object with specified values not overwrites.

Comment: should I use angular.extend or Object.assign ? I am developing an ionic application

Comment: If you want to do it in angular way, go for this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning second time Try

> angular.merge(mser.aa, {c:5,d:2})

Answer (score 0):

You can have your controller like this..

```
 .controller('abc', function ($scope, mser) 
 {
  mser.aa = {a:5, b:2};
  mser.aa.c =5;
  mser.aa.d =2;
  $scope.inps = mser.aa.a  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`mser.aa` is a regular JavaScript property - if you assign an object to the property, it overrides the existing one.
What you want to do is to modify the existing object.
Just like this:

```
mser.aa.a = 5;
mser.aa.b = 2;
mser.aa.c = 5;
mser.aa.d = 2;
```